# Angular 2: md-select along with reactive forms throws error

Tags: angular, angular-material2

Trying to get those two working along, I am using reactive forms all over my application, even on this same component, so I believe it has nothing to do with angular reactive forms dependencies.

template:

```
<md-select placeholder="Tipo da Conta" formControlName="tipoDaContaBancaria">
  <md-option *ngFor="let opt of tiposConta"
          [value]="opt.value">{{opt.label}}</md-option>
</md-select>
```

component:

```
@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'entidade-form.component.ts',
  templateUrl: 'entidade-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['entidade-form.component.css']
})
export class EntidadeFormComponent implements OnInit {

  form: FormGroup;
  tiposConta = [{value: 'CONTA_CORRENTE', label: 'Conta Corrente'}, {value: 'POUPANCA', label: 'Poupança'}];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      tipoDaContaBancaria: ['']
    });
  }
}
```

error:
`No value accessor for form control with name: 'tipoDaContaBancaria'`

Comment: Are you importing both the FormsModule as well as the ReactiveFormsModule in your app module?

Comment: Tested your code, and if you have FormsModule and ReactiveFormsModule in you app module, this should work :)

Comment: Just found out that the problem was that I wasn't importing `MdSelectModule`

Answer (score 1):

Importing `MdSelectModule`inside `Module` fixes the problem